# How to get values from select form to a python file with Flask

Tags: flask

I've created a select options with `html` and `templating` in `flask`.
What I need to accomplish is to take the `option` values and put it inside my code, here is my `html` code :

```
<select id="oblast_select" name='areaid'>
 <option value="0">0</option>
 <option value="5971">value1</option>
 <option value="7402">value2</option>
 <option value="5219">value3</option>
 <option value="4949">value4</option>
 <option value="5764">value5</option>
 <option value="7412">6</option>
 <option value="6217">value7</option>
 <option value="6802">value8</option>
 <option value="6940">value9</option>
</select>
```

Also here is my `java` code that sends post request to `python` file:

```
   var serviceid = document.getElementById("name_street").value;
   var areaid = document.getElementById('oblast_select').value;
   $(".btn").addClass("clicked");

   $.post(
      "/serviceidlookup",
      { serviceid: serviceid },
      { areaid: areaid }
   ).done(function (reply) {
      $(".spinner").css("display", "block");
      $('.spinner').fadeOut(5500);

      setTimeout(function() {

        $('#reply').empty().append(reply).fadeIn(3000);

      }, 4000);`enter code here`
      });
```

and finally my `python` file `run.py`:

```
@app.route('/serviceidlookup', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def serviceidlookup():

    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
    sys.stdout.encoding

    serviceid = request.form.get('serviceid')
    areaid = request.args.get('areaid')
    idarea = str(areaid)
    con = psycopg2.connect(**config)
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("select ate,ate_type,name_kg,name_ru,name_en,parent from ate_history where ate in (select ate from street_ate where street in (select street from street_history where name_ru = '%s') and parent = %s)" %(serviceid,idarea))
    entries = [dict(ate=row[0], ate_type=row[1], name_kg=row[2], name_ru=row[3], name_en=row[4], parent=row[5]) for row in cur.fetchall()]


    return render_template('lookup.html', serviceid=serviceid, entries=entries)
```

After running this code, in the terminal gives me this error :

```
**LINE 1: ...om street_history where name_ru = 'None') and parent = None)**
```

infact, i get the serviceid value from the input field that i've created, it didn't get the other value which is in our case on of the options so for example 7402 to be inside the query at this part :

```
and parent = %s)"
```

Please any help would be toooooooons appreciated !!!!!!!

Comment: Hey community any help over here please !!

Answer (score 0):

You have written

```
serviceid = request.form.get('serviceid')
areaid = request.args.get('areaid')
```

Try changing areaid to match the serviceid i.e

```
serviceid = request.form.get('serviceid')
areaid = request.form.get('areaid')
```

Edit: Try replacing

```
var areaid = document.getElementById('oblast_select').value;
```

with this..

```
var e = document.getElementById("oblast_select");
var areaid= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Edit2: Change your jQuery post to this..

```
$.post(
  "/serviceidlookup",
  { serviceid: serviceid },
  { areaid: areaid } , function (reply) {
      $(".spinner").css("display", "block");
      $('.spinner').fadeOut(5500);

      setTimeout(function() {

          $('#reply').empty().append(reply).fadeIn(3000);

       }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: the same thing bro it gives me the first value but not the second, here is the error :

**LINE 1: ...reet_history where name_ru = 'Ахунбаева') and parent = None)**

you see the first value in place but **areaid** is **None** where it suppose to be one of the options up in the html code !

Comment: I tried that out, it gives me inside the java console this error :

**POST http://127.0.0.1/serviceidlookup 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR),**

also inside the terminal again this error : 

**LINE 1: ...reet_history where name_ru = 'Ахунбаева') and parent = None)**

you see the first value in place but areaid is **None**, the problem is that the request contains the field value that i wrote which is **(Ахунбаева)** but the areaid value is missed somewhere :(,
maybe our problem is in here :

**$.post(
      "/serviceidlookup",
      { serviceid: serviceid },
      { areaid: areaid }**

????????

Comment: I really appreciate your interest, really good guys out there :).

it still the same thing dude !!

Comment: i've tried all of them , but without a val it still on the same error !!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Flask docs - http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict the request.args.get() method will only return the first element by default. To get all the values you need to use a *list method*; request.args.getlist().